# Grails render-plugin does not render images

Tags: image, pdf, grails, render

I have now setup the render-plugin and I get nice PDF-files but I also need to put an image into a few columns in my table. These images are conditionally selected by a data field of the instance.

I have the image in the assets/images folder as I think is the correct place.

I use the following GSP-line in the template that will be used by the renderer to create the PDF.

```
<td><g:if test="${od?.priceFSC > 0.1}"><asset:image src="checkOut16x16.png" width="16" height="16"/></g:if></td>
```

As a HTML-view the images prints perfect but when render the PDF they are missing.

I checked the documentation and tried the code from the example:

The controller:

```
def createPDF() {
    def file = new File("asets/CheckOut16x16.png")
    def OfferHeader offerHeader = OfferHeader.get(params.id)
[offerHeader: offerHeader])
    renderPdf(template: "/stocknote/Stocknote", model: [offerHeader: offerHeader,imageBytes: file.bytes],   filename: "Stocknote-"+params.id+".pdf")
}
```

The view:

```
<rendering:inlinePng bytes="${imageBytes}" class="some-class" />
```

I didn't care of the condition here I just wanted to see if it would be printed but it's not because the view crasched:

```
URI
    /stocknote/editStocknote/32
Class
    org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException
Message
    Request processing failed; nested exception is org.grails.gsp.GroovyPagesException: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/stocknote/editStocknote.gsp:32] [views/stocknote/_StocknoteDetail.gsp:3] 'bytes' is required
Caused by
    [views/stocknote/editStocknote.gsp:32] [views/stocknote/_StocknoteDetail.gsp:3] 'bytes' is required
```

I don't know what I've done wrong but error message seems confusing, "Bytes is required" but I have bytes="${imageBytes}".
Hope someone could give me some help or explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the path to your file is incorrect, try:

Controller:

```
def assetResourceLocator

def createPDF() {
    def file = assetResourceLocator.findAssetForURI( 'CheckOut16x16.png' )
    def OfferHeader offerHeader = OfferHeader.get(params.id)
    [offerHeader: offerHeader])
    renderPdf(template: "/stocknote/Stocknote", model: [offerHeader: offerHeader,imageBytes: file.getByteArray()],   filename: "Stocknote-"+params.id+".pdf")
}
```

View should be fine as is.

Comment: That worked, but I made a mistake >_<. The template that is used to create the PDF is also used by the view where you execute the report. So the error occurred when the view was rendered. I had to check if the image exist in the template before rendering

Answer (score 0):

Made a big mistake >_<, The template used to create the PDF is also used by the view from where you order the PDF and at that time the image has not been created by the controller.
So to come through, I had to check the value of the image before rendering.

```
<g:if test="${imageBytes!= null}"> <rendering:inlinePng bytes="${imageBytes}" /></g:if>
```

That what was needed.